# How many meals a days did the Israelites eat in the wilderness?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 16:

> 12b Tell them, ‘At **twilight** you will eat meat, and in the **morning** you will be filled with bread. Then you will know that I am the LORD your God.’

Did they just have two standard meals a day, one at twilight and one in the morning, and snacking in between? Did the family gather together for lunch as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Did they just have two standard meals a day, one at twilight and one in the morning, and snacking in between? Did the family gather together for lunch as well?"

Yes, two meals were normal through the biblical time period.  The first meal in the morning wasn't usually wasn't as soon as they got up.  See references.

**Appendix: References**

> MEALS, MEAL-TIME, ETC.

1. It was customary among the ancient Hebrews, as among their contemporaries in the East in classical lands, to have but two meals a day. The “morning morsel” or “early snack,” as it is called in the Talmud, taken with some relish like olives, oil or melted butter, might be used by peasants, fishermen, or even artisans, to “break their fast” (see the one reference to it in the New Testament in Jn 21:12, 15), but this was not a true meal. It was rather [ἄριστον πρωϊνόν, ariston proinon] (Robinson, BRP, II, 18), though some think it the [ἄριστον, ariston], of the New Testament (Edersheim, Life and Times of Jesus the Messiah, II, 205, note 3; compare Plummer, International Critical Commentary, on Lk 11:37). To “eat a meal,” i.e. a full meal, in the morning was a matter for grave reproach (Eccl 10:16), as early drinking was unusual and a sign of degradation (of Acts 2:15).
2. The first meal (of “meal-time,” literally, “the time of eating,” Ruth 2:14; Gen 43:16), according to general usage, was taken at or about noon when the climate and immemorial custom demanded a rest from labor. Peter’s intended meal at Joppa, interrupted by the messengers of Cornelius, was at “the sixth hour,” i.e. 12 M. It corresponded somewhat to our modern “luncheon,” but the hour varied according to rank and occupation (Shabbath 10a). The Bedawi take it about 9 or 10 o’clock (Burckhardt, Notes, I, 69). It is described somewhat fully by Lane in Modern Egyptians. To abstain from this meal was accounted “fasting” (Jdg 20:26; 1 Sam 14:24). Drummond (Tropical Africa) says his Negro bearers began the day’s work without food.
3. The second and main meal (New Testament, [δει̂πνον, deipnon]) was taken about the set of sun, or a little before or after, when the day’s work was over and the laborers had “come in from the field” (Lk 17:7; 24:29 f). This is the “supper time,” the “great supper” of Lk 14:16, the important meal of the day, when the whole family were together for the evening (Burckhardt, Notes, I, 69). It was the time of the feeding of the multitudes by Jesus (Mk 6:35; Mt 14:15; Lk 9:12), of the eating of the Passover, and of the partaking of the Lord’s Supper. According to Jewish law, and for special reasons, the chief meal was at midday - “at the sixth hour,” according to Josephus (Vita, 54; compare Gen 43:16–25; 2 Sam 24:15 Septuagint). It was Yahweh’s promise to Israel that they should have “bread” in the morning and “flesh” in the evening (Ex 16:12), incidental evidence of one way in which the evening meal differed from that at noon. At this family meal ordinarily there was but one common dish for all, into which all “dipped the sop” (see Mt 26:23; Mk 14:20), so that when the food, cooked in this common stew, was set before the household, the member of the household who had prepared it had no further work to do, a fact which helps to explain Jesus’ words to Martha, `One dish alone is needful’ (Lk 10:42; Hastings Hastings, Dictionary of Christ and the Gospels, under the word “Meals”).
   --
   Orr, J. (Ed.). (1999). In The International standard Bible encyclopedia: 1915 edition. Albany, OR: Ages Software.

> 1101     Regular meals like our breakfast, lunch and supper were unknown in the time of the New Testament. Most people set to work early in the morning and there wasn’t time to first sit down for a meal. The men perhaps packed a piece of bread and a handful of dates, raisins or olives and ate this along the road—or even plucked ears of corn and rubbed them to eat on their way (cf. Mk 2:23)par. The fishermen on the Sea of Galilee baked fish on coals on the beach when they came in with their boats (cf. Jn 21).

> 1102      The midday meal was eaten at around eleven, but it was more a time of rest than lunchtime. The hot climate necessitated a siesta. A piece of bread dipped in water or sometimes wine, together with cheese or raisins or olives would have been enough.

> 1103      The real meal was in the evening after sunset. Then the whole family and all guests sat and ate on mats or on low benches. A meal of meat and vegetables was served in a great bowl and all ate from it with their hands. A piece of bread was rolled into a ball and then dipped into the gravy and eaten.
> --
> Du Plessis, I. J. (1998). The social and economic life of the Jewish people in Palestine in the time of the New Testament. In A. B. du Toit (Ed.), The New Testament Milieu (Vol. 2). Halfway House: Orion Publishers.

Comment: +1 Are there internet links for these references?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You could look for Bible Encyclopedias and Dictionaries.  Milieu deals directly with customs.

Comment: Look for the free books with software packages: https://www.logos.com/product/55923/lexham-intro-collection

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: Olive tree also has many. Search the free books.  Both these software only charge for books, so free books are free.  e.q. https://www.olivetree.com/store/product.php?productid=16581

Comment: If you use Linux or a Chromebook, Logos has a Web app.  Logos also has app for smartphones.

Comment: This reference is in Google Books.  I'm not experienced at using it: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_International_Standard_Bible_Encyclo/6OJvO2jMCr8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bible+encyclopedia&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Great! I have now installed Logos on my phone. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I really like your answer. I started a subreddit at reddit.com/r/BibleVerseCommentary. Can I copy your answer here and share it with the members of my subreddit? Of course, I will attribute the post to your name and hermeneutics.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: @Tony Yes, note it is mostly quotes.